# form page record not store in database

Tags: django

iam trying to store form data in to database . but its not working properly . i need some help what should i do .. this is my html page and view or urls file... when i click on submit record not going to database

```
view.py

def add(request):
    template = loader.get_template('add.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())

def submit(request):

    Name = request.GET.get('name')
    Tb_name = request.GET.get('tb_name')
    Product_name = request.GET.get('product_name')
    Domain_name = request.GET.get('domain_name')
    ssh_ip = request.GET.get('ssh_ip')

    new= Testbeds(name=Name,tb_name=Tb_name, product_name=Product_name, domain_name=Domain_name, ssh_ip=ssh_ip)

    new.save()
    template = loader.get_template('add.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>



    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add-New</title>

     <script src="static/js/script.js"></script>

    <script src="static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}} /static/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}} /static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href=""> Testbeds </a>
        </div>
            <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

             <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Dashboard</a></li>

                    <li><a href="{% url 'add' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        Add New</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
</header> <!--header close-->
<br> <br> <br> <br>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal"  id="form" method="GET"  >{% csrf_token %}


  <div class="form-group">
      <h2 > Add new data:</h2>
      <br>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Tb_Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" name="tb_name" class="form-control" id="tb_name" placeholder="Enter Tb-name">
    </div>

  </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
             <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Product_name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control" id="product_name" placeholder="Enter product name">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Domain_name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" name="domain_name" class="form-control" id="domain_name" placeholder="Enter domain-name">
            </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >ssh_ip:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" name="ssh_ip" class="form-control" id="ssh_ip" placeholder="Enter ssh_ip">
        </div>
        </div>

        <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit"  id="submitTestbeds" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" onclick=" return Testbeds" >
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told your form to submit to the `submit` view, so it is going to the `add` view which contains no code to do anything with the data.

But don't do that. Use a Django form, and read the documentation on [using them in views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view).

Comment: @annonymus you need to set an action on your form. It needs to point the url of the submit view, what ever that is tied to.